# Print multiple pages from TextBox

Tags: c#, list, printing, printdialog

```
private void PrintTextBox(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawString(textBox1.Text, textBox1.Font, Brushes.Black, 50, 20);
}

private void printListButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
    pd.PrintPage += PrintTextBox;
    PrintPreviewDialog ppd = new PrintPreviewDialog();
    ppd.Document = pd;
    ppd.ShowDialog();
}
```

I tried in `PrintTextBox` method using the `e.HasMorePages == true` but then it continously started to add pages. Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a often problem, e.hasmorepages has not a common behavior. e.hasmorepages will fire printtextbox over and over again until you say not to (e.hasmorepages=false).

you have to count the lines, then calculate the space, and if it does not fit in your paper yo decide if document have more pages or does not.

I normally use an integer that counts the lines I will print, if not enough space then e.hasmorages=true;

Check this easier example, you have to add system.drawing.printing

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private string[] Lines = new string[10];
    private int CurrentRow = 0;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Lines[i] = i.ToString("N2");
        }
        PrintDocument pd=new PrintDocument();
        PrintDialog pdi = new PrintDialog();
        pdi.ShowDialog();
        pd.PrinterSettings = pdi.PrinterSettings;
        pd.PrintPage += PrintTextBox;
        pd.Print();
    }

    private void PrintTextBox(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        int y = 0;

        do 
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(Lines[CurrentRow],new Font("Calibri",10),Brushes.Black,new PointF(0,y));
            CurrentRow += 1;
            y += 20;
            if (y > 20) // max px per page
            {
                e.HasMorePages = CurrentRow != Lines.Count(); // check if you need more pages
                break;
            }
        } while(CurrentRow < Lines.Count());
    }
}
```

Comment: Updatem y question little bit, could you check what's still wrong?

Comment: the problem is that your 'i' restarts when you call e.hasmorapages=true; you have to do something like this: (i updated your code). try it and comments please

Comment: It still prints only one page.

Comment: But the code with textBox works but then it shows indexOutOfRange exception.

Comment: try to debug your code, that alwasy helps me, i debuged your code, and the problem is that i missed to add 'fi' to your for limit.

Comment: Oh, I still can't change it.

Comment: sorry but I have no time to fix your code, but I can explain you how e.hasmorepagesworks, and why i see your code is not working.

Comment: But thank you still for help, eh printing was simple untill I tried to print more than one page.

Comment: chek my updated example, im sure you will get the answere with that