# Printing contents from textbox

Tags: c#, printing, visual-studio-2015

I have a problem with the `PrintPreviewDialog`. I get this result:

[image: Result]

All the contents goes into one page. I already tried `\f` and `e.HasMorePages` but with no result:

[image: No luck]

PS. I'm new to c# and stackeroverflow wont allow me to paste the whole code.

```
    private void btnPrintReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        printPreviewDialog1.Document = printDocument1;

        printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(txtInvoices.Text, txtInvoices.Font, Brushes.Black, 10, 25);
       //e.HasMorePages = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to properly format the images - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit your question to provide any additional details necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Comment: [Answer can be found here, just need to tweak a bit.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20149377/print-multiple-pages-from-textbox)